# Are hexadecimal numbers ever negative?

Tags: java, hex, negative-number

Are hexadecimal numbers ever negative? If yes then how?
For binary you would have *signed* and *unsigned*.
How would one represent them in Hex? I need this for a hex routine I am about to embark upon.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you referring to hexadecimal integer literals? (`0xFFFFFFF == -1` would be an example here).

Answer (score 25):

Yes.  For example you'd have the following representations in signed 32-bit binary and hex:

```
Decimal: 1
 Binary: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
    Hex: 00 00 00 01

Decimal: -1
 Binary: 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
    Hex: FF FF FF FF

Decimal: -2
 Binary: 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110
    Hex: FF FF FF FE
```

As you can see, the Hex representation of negative numbers is directly related to the binary representation.

Comment: This follows 2's complement representation of negative numbers as they would be in binary. I know it's the most wide representation of signed binary numbers, however, it's specific to binary, right? This answer takes a base 10, performs 2's compliment, and outputs a base 16 conversion of the literal binary output. I know a "signed" base 10 is represented by a negative sign, is that not the same for base 16? Does -0xF not convert to -15? I know a signed binary requires context, right? because 1111 == -1 or 1111 == 15. The sign adds context. I've never seen a signed hex, and am curious. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

The high bit of a number determines if it is negative. So for instance an int is 32 bits long, so if bit 31 is a 1 it is negative. Now how you display that value be it hexadecimal or decimal doesn't matter. so the hex values like

```
0x80000000
0x91345232
0xA3432032
0xBFF32042
0xC33252DD
0xE772341F
0xFFFFFFFF
```

are all negative, because the top bit is set to 1

```
       |
       v
0x8 -> 1000
0x9 -> 1001
0xA -> 1010
0xB -> 1011
0xC -> 1100
0xD -> 1101
0xE -> 1110
0xF -> 1111
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes they can be. It's the same as binary as to how you interpret it (signed vs unsigned).

Answer (score 5):

You would take the binary signed and unsigned forms then represent them in hex as you would any binary number.

Answer (score 3):

On one hand, why not - it's just a positional numeric system, like decimal.

On the other hand, they normally use hex notation to deduce the underlying bit pattern - and that is much more straightforward if the number is interpreted as unsigned.

So the answer is -  it's possible, mathematically correct and internally consistent, but defeats the most common purpose of hex notation.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, these are the bounds of the `Integer` data type:

```
Integer.MIN_VALUE = 0x80000000; 
Integer.MAX_VALUE = 0x7fffffff;
```

Comment: ref code  :http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.0MAX_VALUE