# How to tell if a hexadecimal number is negative?

Tags: binary, negative-number

My question is: Is there a definite system that says that if the first bit (when we turn our hexadecimal number to binary) is a 1 then the hexadecimal number is negative? Is this a definite rule for the computer that the first bit always defines if the number is negative or positive? Thanks in advance!

Comment: duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629416/how-to-tell-if-hex-value-is-negative

Comment: Hex is a _numeral_ system, not a specific way to represent numbers using binary values (such as two's complement), so the question doesn't really make sense. It depends on how the bits are interpreted – which the hexadecimal system does not dictate.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, without diving into two's compliments and arithmetic, the leading bit is the sign bit.  Here is some reading on the math exchange forum for you:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408761/hexadecimal-value-of-a-negative-number

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement