# Why do Powershell and the WinAPI recognize huge numbers as negative numbers when seeking in a file?

Tags: winapi, rust, numbers, hex

I'm studying the NTFS filesystem, and I have a weird problem when trying to seek in `\\.\PhysicalDrive0` with a huge number like `0xb2ec0000` (`3001810944`). The `$MFT` of my Windows partition is supposed to reside at that offset (which is the case).

When I was seeking from that number (even from the decimal form: `3001810944`), `SetFilePointer` returned `ERROR_NEGATIVE_SEEK`, so I decided to learn how negative numbers work in hexadecimal.

From [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629416/how-to-tell-if-hex-value-is-negative) topic, I understood why `0xb2ec0000` was considered as negative, because it starts with `b`. Powershell also recognizes it as negative:

```
PS A:\core> 0xb2ec0000
-1293156352
```

It can't only be a negative number, if we exclude the existence of negative numbers in hexadecimal, from some [hexadecimal to decimal](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter) converters we realize that it's also equal to `3001810944`.

To successfully seek at offset `0xb2ec0000`, I decided to seek two times of `3001810944 / 2` bytes (`1500905472`), it worked fine, but it's a problem if some natural numbers are considered as negative if they aren't in the given context, it doesn't seem normal at all.

And concerning the division, if I decide to do `0xb2ec0000 / 2` it outputs:

```
PS A:\core> 0xb2ec0000 / 2
-646578176
```

but

```
PS A:\core> 3001810944 / 2 
1500905472
```

Here is the Rust code of the program:

You can reproduce the example by opening `\\.\PhysicalDrive0` and seeking at offset `0xb2ec0000`:

```
extern "system"{
    // [...]
    fn CreateFileA(a: *const u8, b: u32, c: u32, d: *mut c_void, e: u32, f: u32, g: *mut c_void) -> *mut c_void;
    fn SetFilePointer(a: *mut c_void, b: i64, c: *mut i32, d: u32) -> i32;  
}
// [...]

let boot = CreateFileA(
    "\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0\0".as_ptr(),
    25,
    0x00000002 | 0x00000001,
    null_mut(),
    3,
    128,
    null_mut()
);

// [...] Calculating $MFT offset

let mft_offset: i64 = mft_logical_cluster * (bpb.wBytesPerSec * bpb.uchSecPerClust as u16) as i64 + (dsk_info.dwRelativeSector * 512) as i64;

println!("{:x}", mft_offset); // outputs 0xb2ec0000

if(SetFilePointer(boot,mft_offset,null_mut(),0) == -1){
    println!("Error: {}", GetLastError()); // outputs 131
}
```

Comment: You need to show us some lines of relevant code.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I added the code, it's in Rust and I skipped the non-important part to understand the actual problem. You can reproduce it by yourself by simply opening `\\.\PhysicalDrive0` and performing the seek operation at offset `0xb2ec0000`.

Comment: this is because you set *lpDistanceToMoveHigh* (*A pointer to the high order 32-bits of the signed 64-bit distance to move*) to 0. and *lDistanceToMove* (*The low order 32-bits of a signed value*) is signed expand.. and i will tell you a terrible secret - use `SetFilePointer[Ex]` at all have no sense

Comment: in place `null_mut()` must be pointer to 0 dword. but not need call `SetFilePointer` at all. for what ?!

Comment: You also should do some more research about bits, bytes and how they are interpreted. "hexidecimal" is not signed or unsigned. For example, `0xff` can represent *either* `255` or `-1` depending on how you interpret it.

Answer (score 4):

You have incorrectly defined `SetFilePointer` as taking an `i64` when it is an `i32`.

If you take the time to thoroughly read the docs for [`SetFilePointer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointer), you'll see:

> **`lDistanceToMove`**
>
> The low order 32-bits of a signed value that specifies the number of
>   bytes to move the file pointer.
>
> If `lpDistanceToMoveHigh` is not `NULL`, `lpDistanceToMoveHigh` and
>   `lDistanceToMove` form a single 64-bit signed value that specifies the
>   distance to move.
>
> If `lpDistanceToMoveHigh` is `NULL`, `lDistanceToMove` is a 32-bit signed
>   value. A positive value for `lDistanceToMove` moves the file pointer
>   forward in the file, and a negative value moves the file pointer back.
>
> **`lpDistanceToMoveHigh`**
>
> A pointer to the high order 32-bits of the signed 64-bit distance to
>   move.
>
> If you do not need the high order 32-bits, this pointer must be set to
>   `NULL`.

You will need to split the `i64` into two parts and pass each part separately, the high bits as a pointer to a value.

You should **not** be attempting to write the FFI definitions yourself (because you'll get them wrong). Ideally, use the [winapi crate](https://crates.io/crates/winapi), which has the correct definition for [`SetFilePointer`](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.8/winapi/um/fileapi/fn.SetFilePointer.html).

Even better, just use regular Rust types like [`File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html) and [`Seek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html).